# Oracle 10g standby не накатываются standby logs на табличное Tablespace

Tags: oracle, dba

С толкнулся с причиной что логи изменений с Primary db не накатываются на Standby db.

проверка наличия логоа на Standby сервере:

```
SQL> SELECT THREAD#, SEQUENCE# FROM V$ARCHIVED_LOG;
```

Проверяю состояние базы:

```
SQL> select name,open_mode,log_mode from v$database;
SQL> select recovery_mode from v$archive_dest_status;
```

### RECOVERY_MODE

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

MANAGED REAL TIME APPLY

Проверяю последний номер архивного журнала на Standby сервере:

```
SQL> select max(sequence#) from v$log_history;
```

Проверяю текущей роли экземпляра:

```
SQL> select name, database_role from v$database;
```

Проверяю применяются логи к

```
SQL> select process, status, thread#, sequence#, block# from v$managed_standby;
```

Но все как то неработает.
Заранее спасибо!